# Using multiple between date statements makes this query run in one second. But using one or the other makes it run forever

Tags: sql, oracle

Why does this statement run in one second when I have both between statements in it as opposed to just using one or the other? It takes forever if I comment one out. It's two different ways to pull data from the previous month (except one is converting from UTC to local time). But it only works if I have both.

```
SELECT *
FROM DUAL D
WHERE D.ARRIVE_DT_TM BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)+1)
    AND D.ARRIVE_DT_TM BETWEEN cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1),'MONTH'),1,126,1) AND cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-(1/86400),1,126,1)
```

Confused!

Comment: What do the EXPLAIN PLANs show for the different queries?

Comment: Do they both return the same number of records?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE FUNCTION`) statements for your tables and for the `cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc` function; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that replicates your issues; the full queries you use in each example; details of the indexes you have on the table; the explain plans for each of the queries.

Comment: Do both take the same time? I'm wondering if `cclsql_cnvtdatetimeutc` is slow. Is it deterministic? Is it defined as `pragma udf`?

Comment: If you really have a table or object named `DUAL` you should rename it. `DUAL` is the name of a special Oracle table that should always contain one row, and creating your own copy could cause problems.